# Pester BoundParams in CallHistory empty

Tags: unit-testing, powershell, pester

I have a simple that at this point doesn't do anything, I am just getting started with Pester, but my goal is to mock Remove-ADGroupMember and a few other AD powershell commands for testing.

```
Param(
  [string]$computerList = ".\\computers.csv",
  [boolean]$isTest = $false
)

function Remove-Groups(){
  Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "dale" -Members "dale","cameron"
}
```

and my test script

```
$here = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$sut = "../" + (Split-Path -Leaf $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path).Replace(".Tests.", ".")
. "$here\$sut"

Describe "UninstallUnused - Remove-Groups" {
    It "does something useful" {
      Mock Remove-ADGroupMember
      Remove-Groups
      Assert-MockCalled Remove-ADGroupMember -Exactly 1
      Assert-MockCalled Remove-ADGroupMember 1 -ParameterFilter {$Identity -eq "dale" -and $Members -contains "dale"}
    }
}
```

The First `Assert-MockCalled` line works, but no matter what I try on the second one the tests always fails. After  awhile I dug into the Assert-MockCalled funciton with a debugger and it looks like the values of the -Members parameter are getting lost

[image]

In the picture above I'm in the Assert-MockCalled function of Mock.ps1 and as you can see the values passed to members are missing. If I only pass 1 value to the Remove-ADGroupMember mock like so: `Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "dale" -Members "dale"` the value I see in BoundParams is `{}` instead of `{, }` as you see in the screenshot.

Is this an issue with the way I'm doing it or is the problem the way the pester is reading the params etc. from Remove-ADGroupMember?

Comment: If you only do the second `Assert-MockCalled` does it work or are the `Members` values still being lost?

Comment: Yes... I commented out the first Assert-MockCalled statement and Members = {, }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Identity nor the Members parameters are of type String, so that's why your assertions do not work.

- Identity - Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup
- Members - Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPrincipal[]

So in order to make the filter work you need to cast to string (the types luckily serialize to the names you need)

```
function Remove-Groups(){
  Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "dale" -Members "dale","cameron"
}

Describe "UninstallUnused - Remove-Groups" {
    It "does something useful" {
      Mock Remove-ADGroupMember
      Remove-Groups
      Assert-MockCalled Remove-ADGroupMember -Exactly 1
      Assert-MockCalled Remove-ADGroupMember 1 -ParameterFilter {
        Write-Host ( $identity.GetType(),$members.GetType()) ; #otputting the data types
        ([string[]]$members) -contains "dale" -and ([string]$identity) -eq "dale" }
    }
}
```

*Edit:*
You could also use the automatic casting to the left parameter, but that makes the code easier to break:

```
 ([string[]]$members -contains "dale") -and ("dale" -eq $identity)
```

Comment: **Yep, that worked thanks**. I thought that since I was passing a string to the Remove-ADGroupMember call I would have to test for a string.